# Start a disabled windows service?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-services

How do I start a disabled windows service from command line?

NET START "Service" doesn't work on disabled services

Comment: In the UI: go to services, find your service, double click (or right-click, then properties), startup type=Manual. If it is slated for deletion, restart your computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sc.exe` utility to enable the service and optionally start it as well.

To enable a service you need to set any start option except disabled:

```
sc.exe config [ServiceName] start= [option]
```

> start= {boot | system | auto | demand | disabled | delayed-auto}
>
> Specifies the start type for the service.
>
> boot - Specifies a device driver that is loaded by the boot loader.
>
> system - Specifies a device driver that is started during kernel 
>   initialization.
>
> auto - Specifies a service that automatically starts each time the computer is restarted and runs even if no one logs on to the computer.
>
> demand - Specifies a service that must be started manually. This is the default value.
>
> delayed-auto - Specifies a service that starts automatically a short time after other auto services are started.

Then you can manually run it by executing:

```
sc.exe start [ServiceName]
```

Comment: This is an example of why not to use links.  This link is no longer valid.

Comment: sc.exe start [ServiceName] got the service running for me

Answer (score 10):

open command line(cmd.exe) and use this:

```
sc config "ServiceName" start= auto
```

Becareful, it's not `start = auto` or `start=auto` or `start =auto`.

Answer (score 0):

u can use the sc command

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true